# Multi Worksheet Change code not completing

Tags: excel, vba

This code only works some of the time. The first change event is always triggered, but the second event does not. The formula insertion does not alwaqys happen when I am starting with a cleared out worksheet and adding new shift data. After With Target is random. Any ideas on why this does not run consistently?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim DestWH As String
    Dim DWHRowNum As Long
    Dim toDay As String, nextDay As String
    DWHRowNum = 2
    toDay = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    nextDay = Format(Date + 1, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Do Until Cells(DWHRowNum, 2).Value = ""
        Select Case Cells(DWHRowNum, 6).Value
        Case "ABQ1", "CLE2", "DEN3", "GEG1", "LIT1", "ORD5", "ORF3", "PAE2", "PCW1", "SLC1"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = toDay
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
        Case "BFI4", "DEN4", "PDX9", "SMF1"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = nextDay
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "04:30"
        End Select
        DWHRowNum = DWHRowNum + 1
    Loop
    ' ** Update
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("N2:N28")) Is Nothing Then
                Dim vValue
                vValue = .Value
                If Len(vValue) > 0 And IsDate(vValue) Then
                    If Not Me.Range("Q2").HasFormula Then
                        Me.Range("Q2:Q28").Formula = "=IF(G2="""","""",IF(AND(M2="""",N2>G2),""Future"",""Current""))"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The *Worksheet Change* event will fire whether you enter a value in `A1` or `XFD1048576`. Surely you don't want it to do anything in either case i.e. you want to restrict the 1st part of the code to a specific range usually a single-column range (like you did with the 2nd part). Column `B` looks like a candidate but we can't be sure. Please accurately explain what should happen and when, e.g. *"if a value changes in `B`, run both parts of the code but if a change happens in `N`, run only the 2nd part"*. Fill in the details.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks. So column F2:F28 has dropdowns. When an item from the dropdown is selected, the 1st part should trigger. When a date is manually input into the corresponding row in column N, then the 2nd part should trigger adding the formula into the corresponding row in column Q.

Comment: Always consider that the user may change a lot of things (like pressing del while selection is multiple cells) It's also good to check if target.rows.count and .columns.count match what you're trying to catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the same logic to validate `Target` for the 1st part

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim DestWH      As String
    Dim DWHRowNum   As Long
    Dim toDay       As String, nextDay As String
    Dim vValue
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        vValue = .Cells(1).Value
        If .CountLarge = 1 And Len(vValue) > 0 Then
            If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F2:F28")) Is Nothing Then
                DWHRowNum = 2
                toDay = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
                nextDay = Format(Date + 1, "mm/dd/yyyy")
                Do Until Cells(DWHRowNum, 2).Value = ""
                    Select Case Cells(DWHRowNum, 6).Value
                        Case "ABQ1", "CLE2", "DEN3", "GEG1", "LIT1", "ORD5", "ORF3", "PAE2", "PCW1", "SLC1"
                            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = toDay
                            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
                        Case "BFI4", "DEN4", "PDX9", "SMF1"
                            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = nextDay
                            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "04:30"
                    End Select
                    DWHRowNum = DWHRowNum + 1
                Loop
            ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("N2:N28")) Is Nothing Then                
                If IsDate(vValue) Then
                    If Not Me.Range("Q2").HasFormula Then
                        Me.Range("Q2:Q28").Formula = "=IF(G2="""","""",IF(AND(M2="""",N2>G2),""Future"",""Current""))"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The vValue declaration is in the 2nd part and causing a compile error (Variable Not Defined) in the first part.

Comment: Moved the Dim vValue to the upper section with the rest of the Dim statements and moved the vValue = .Value to the next line after the first If Nothing Then. Compiled the code (no errors), saved and closed the workbook. Reopened and no luck.

Comment: As with the other iterations, it seems to work with the first entry in the worksheet then stops working.

Comment: I've update the code. Please run `Application.EnableEvents = True` in Immediate window  OR close and re-open the workbook before testing.

Comment: So far so good. Thank you for your patience and diligence. Much appreciated!

Comment: So we are back to square one. This morning the code did not update the formula cells after the cell change in column F.

Comment: There are lot of possible reasons. eg. users didn't enable macro when opening the file, Application.EnableEvents is wrong , etc. Try to add `Debug.Print Target.Address` in `Worksheet_Change` as the 1st code line. The output in the immediate window tells you if Worksheet_Change is activated after users edit.

Comment: Sorry, got caught in a side project. Will try this tomorrow and get back to you.